# (Android) What are these variable?

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-studio, sharedpreferences

source: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057858/13718592)

```
//Retrieve the values
Set<String> set = myScores.getStringSet("key", null);

//Set the values
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.addAll(listOfExistingScores);
scoreEditor.putStringSet("key", set);
scoreEditor.commit();
```

- is `myScores` refers to sharedpreference?
- what is `listOfExistingScores` refers to? is it ArrayList?
- is `scoreEditor` refers to ArrayList? or ListView? or custom ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that answser you can say that those three variable defines following things :

**myScores :**

As you said in op, it's shared preference variable. It holdes `sharedpreference`.

**listOfExistingScores :**

It refers to the array declared by user. It is stored in hashset.

**scoreEditor :**

Score editor is [sharedpreferences editor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor). You can read more details about it by given link.